Comportamento diferente entre React e html puro pós drag and drop
Por algum motivo, ao passar o mouse em cima da div vermelha(filho) após o drag and drop, o evento onMouseMove da div azul(Pai) não é acionado no React, mas é acionado no HTML puro.
Estou esquecendo algo?
Teste no React: https://playcode.io/1861106
Teste com HTML:


function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('id', ev.target.id);
  }

  function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('id');
    var element = document.getElementById(data);
    ev.target.appendChild(element);
  }

  function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function mouseMove(event) {
    console.clear();
    console.log('onMouseMoveDiagram', event.clientX, event.clientY);
  }
<div>
    <div
      id="child"
      draggable="true"
      ondragstart="drag(event)"
      style="background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 200px;"
    >
        1. Put me on blue container<br/>
        2. Check console<br/>
        3. Move mouse over containers
    </div>

    <div
      id="newParent"
      ondrop="drop(event)"
      onmousemove="mouseMove(event)"
      ondragover="allowDrop(event)"
      style="background-color: blue; width: 400px; height: 400px;"
    ></div>
</div>




No React, você não deveria alterar o DOM diretamente como está fazendo. Precisa reescrever com base em estados e efeitos, e deixar o React mexer no DOM.
